# How to continue using GitBash after calling gitk?

Tags: github, terminal, command, line, gitk

After using some commands e.g. `gitk` I can't keep using the terminal. I need to terminate `gitk` and then I can keep typing commands. Is there a way to open a program and keep using the terminal? I'm using GitBash on Windows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
gitk &
```

The `&` causes the command to run in the background.

As an alternative, you can interrupt a program by pressing `Control-Z` in the terminal. This gives you back control of the command-line, but pauses the program. You can continue it in the background by typing

```
bg
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking for! Cheers!

Comment: i added this to a .bashrc file in my home dir `alias gitk="gitk &"`